# how to fix unexpected symbol in "+ pip install"

Tags: r

This is the code I entered.

```
hello <- c(1,2,3)
```

This error is showing after I run the above command.

`[Running] Rscript "c:\Users\KARAN\Desktop\code\test.r" Error: unexpected symbol in "+ pip install" Execution halted`

Comment: The R code and the way you're running the script look fine to me. Perhaps you have something unrelated going on. For example, some R startup script that tries to install some libraries. How did you install R?

Comment: Have you use `reticulate` package to install python packages from `rstudio` ?

Comment: looks like you trying to run python with R code, if you running r you should not get anything related to pip